# My JavaScript while loop is exiting after an incorrect text input is entered twice

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prompt

This question has been solved, see comments below.

I changed the following lines:

```
|10    while (!quest1a.includes(userInput.toLowerCase().trim())) {

|13    if (quest1a.includes(userInput.toLowerCase().trim())) {
```

I can't seem to fix this. The loop will exit entirely. The console error is `script.js:133 Uncaught TypeError: quest1a.toString(...).toLowerCase(...).includes(...).trim is not a function`

The error is occurring at line 13 in this snippet of code:

```
1| const quest1a = ['north', 'up', 1];
2| const quest1b = ['east', 'right', 2];
3|
4| let userInput = prompt(q1).toLowerCase().trim();
5| userInput;
6|
7| while (true) {
8|    userInput = prompt(q1);
9|
10|     while (userInput.trim() === "" || !quest1a.toString().toLowerCase().includes(userInput).trim()) {
11|         userInput = prompt(`Please use a correct entry. \n \n ${q1}`);}
12|
13|     if (quest1a.toString().toLowerCase().includes(userInput).trim()) {
14|         break;
15|         } else {
16|             continue;
17|         }
18|     }
```

It will loop one time, and will prompt the user a second time, but the second input throws the error.

I'm not sure what more I can try. It appears as if the parenthesis are being removed for some reason. I am expecting the loop to repeat if incorrect text is entered.

Comment: `quest1a.toString().toLowerCase().includes(userInput).trim()`  This bit of code doesn't really make sense.  Did you maybe mean ->  `quest1a.includes(userInput.toLowerCase.trim())`

Comment: `includes` returns `boolean`. `boolean` doesn't have a `trim` method

Comment: It's worded that way because I tend to overcomplicate things without realizing. I forget what I did initially, but I left toString out and it didn't work, but ended up working when I added it. But Your line is more succinct, thank you!
I changed the code to `quest1a.includes(userInput.toLowerCase.trim())`, but the error is still thrown.

Comment: Oops, I left `()` out of `toLowerCase` in Keiths suggestion. The issue is solved, thanks guys! I'm very new, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @reric88 Oops, yeah. my bad.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript basics problem. I don’t know why you want to transform your array to string using the toString method but every time you do something you don’t know or you don’t expect some output just copy the array in another variable (using the copy method because you’re gonna duplicate the content and not the reference) and don’t use the same array for the same operations, just create another variable and save it on it. In this case you want to trim a boolean and is a little bit weird you can write the while like this:

``` const quest1aTrimmed = quest1a.includes(userInput) ? quest1a.toString().toLowerCase().trim() : undefined; while (userInput.trim() === "" || !quest1aTrimmed) { userInput = prompt(``Please use a correct entry. \n \n ${q1}``); quest1aTrimmed = quest1a.includes(userInput) ? quest1a.toString().toLowerCase().trim() : undefined; } ```